# I'm trying to better understand the use of `this`. The example is verbose, but its for the purpose of trying to better understand

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, this

I'm trying to better understand the use of `this`. In experimenting with this code, I found I can access the items in `arr` by using something like `console.log(this.arr[4])`, but only if `arr` is declared using `var`. If I declare `arr` using `let` or `const`, I get a TypeError.

First, I do understand this is verbose. Like I said, I am just experimenting to try and get a better understanding and came across this issue that piqued my curiosity.

```js
const arr = [
  1,
  false,
  {
    name: 'John',
    address: '123 Peachtree Drive'
  },
  function(name = 'new user') {
    const greeting = 'Hello there, '
    console.log(greeting + name)
  },
  'foo',
]

console.log(this.arr[4])
```

Again, if I simply declare `arr` using `var` instead of `let` I can log it just fine.

Comment: `this` makes no sense, should just be `console.log(arr[4])`

Comment: You should just read up on ["this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), there's no proper question to answer here.

Comment: You are not using `let` in your code sample... That said, good job using "piqued" :).

Comment: @epascarello. I understand I could just use `console.log(arr[4])`. The idea was that I thought `console.log(this.arr[4])` would have the same result, and it did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a browser, top-level `this` is `window`, and top-level `var` declarations also make variables accessible as properties of `window`, while `let` and `const` do not. The correct way to reference `arr` is simply

```
console.log(arr[4])
```

I would discourage you from using top-level `this` to even access `var` declarations, because code which relies on that behavior of `var` is obviously confusing, as this case is a perfect example of.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're getting confused about is not specific to 'this'. It is related to scope. 'var' has a different scope than 'let' or 'const'.

```
var - has function level scoping and can change the value reference
let - has block level scoping and can change the value reference
const - has block level scoping but cannot change the value reference
```

https://love2dev.com/blog/javaScript-var-let-const/

Be precise about how and where you declare your variables as this is an important part of JavaScript syntax/interpretation.