# var doesn't attach to global

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, var

I am trying to understand this keyword. but the problem is with the node environment. I am getting the expected behavior in Chrome Developer tool but the same code isn't working fine in the node environment.

When we create a var in the global context, it is supposed to be inside the global (node) or window (browser) but in node environment, it doesn't get attached to document.

I am just testing a simple 3 lines of code which works totally fine in chrome.

This is for Node environment

```
var color = 'red';

console.log(this.color);
console.log(global.color)
```

and this is for Browser which works fine

```
var color = 'red';

console.log(this.color);
console.log(window.color)
```

For the node environment, I am receiving undefined which is not expected.

Comment: In Node, code is always scoped to a *module*.

Comment: Node.js files are implicitly wrapped in an IIFE, so it would be the equivalent of `(function () { var color = 'red'; console.log(window.color); })();` in a browser.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908340/1541563). tl;dr _don't rely on `var` attaching to global namespace. Even when it works, it's confusing to those reading your code._

Answer (score 3):

Here's a software development rule: don't rely on variables sticking on `this`, `global`, or `module`-related objects. Scope can vary and lead to unexpected behavior and bugs. Use explicit `(this|global|module.exports).varName` bindings.

But if you just want to understand how things work in Node:

- Code is wrapped into an IIFE when executed, setting the `this` value to `module.exports` (not `global`).
- Access to `global` is persistent across modules, so if you write `global.foo='foo'` in a module then require it in `bar.js`, `global.foo` will be set to `'foo'` in `bar.js`. *It is discouraged to directly use `global` for most use cases - stick to `exports` and `require`*.
- According to [the specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-environment-records), `var` is not supposed to make things stick to `global`: there are some exceptions (see below), but you should not rely on that when writing code

Related questions:

- [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object)
- [Meaning of “this” in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/8186898)

Comment: Okay, so from what I understand is that this in nodejs refers to an empty object which is module.exports, right? Now please clarify me a little bit about global on nodejs. Does it refers to whole environment and our module.exprorts get attach to global?

Comment: Define *attach*

Comment: I mean module.exports make it a property of global. but nvm, I researched on it and clarified myself.